# Eshell: commands, syntaxes, etc

Tags: emacs, eshell

Just found that unfinished manual, but it's really unfineshed. Right on the climax. I still don't get it.

- What is that? An eLisp interpreter?
- How do you tell emacs to edit a file from there?
- What is the difference?
- What are the eshell only commands?

Comment: very badly asked question IMHO - can you re-edit to be a bit clearer / specific about what you're asking. also, consider splitting into separate questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eshell is a command interpreter like a normal shell, but it does not run bash or any other shell underneath. Like bash, it has several types of commands: while bash has aliases, functions, and falls back to $PATH, eshell has aliases, lisp functions, eshell functions, and falls back to $PATH.

So, for example, you can run:

`~ $ find-file foo.txt`

and the lisp function `find-file` will be executed non-interactively (unlike <kbd>M-x</kbd>), meaning all necessary arguments must be passed in. This is one way to tell emacs to edit a file from eshell. It's probably faster to run <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd>, since it will default to the directory that eshell is currently in.

When you run:

`~ $ ls`

it actually runs the function `eshell/ls`, which will get a directory listing without calling `/bin/ls`. There are similar builtins; if you run <kbd>C-h f eshell/ <TAB></kbd> you can get a list of them.

One of the major points of the eshell builtin functions is to make commands fit into other existing emacs functions. For example, `grep` will go into the `*grep*` buffer so that you can quickly jump to the results.

It also has aliases, which are somewhat similar to bash aliases, but act a bit like functions in the way they handle arguments. For example, in bash, you might say

`alias ll='ls -l'`

while in eshell you would say

`alias ll ls -l '$*'`

and both of those mean the same thing. The `$*` means basically "expand all arguments", and it's necessary to quote it. You can run `alias` to see all aliases you've created.

Comment: eshell gives you an uniform shell across platforms (i.e. an ls-command that works the same way on both Linux and Windows).

Comment: Perfect! Just what I wanted, a mix of tutorial, workflow and reference source. Sad the documentation isn't very complete. There are other things I'd like to know, like how to customize the prompt. I think I got to learn a little elisp and dive into the code when I get some time.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this introduction to Eshell:
http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2010/12/13/complete-guide-mastering-eshell/

It probably does not cover every aspect of this powerful tool, but it's quite informative.

Comment: Please provide more than just a link for your answer.